# Query Store plan forcing failed with failure reason NO_PLAN

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, query-store

I have a query in query store for which I have forced a plan.

I can confirm the plan is forced with

```
SELECT * FROM sys.query_store_plan WHERE is_forced_plan = 1
```

and the plan shows up in the results

However, if I look at the `last_force_failure_reason_desc` column, I see `NO_PLAN`

Some Googling took me to the following articles:

[Kendra Little](https://littlekendra.com/2016/03/25/no_plan-and-no_index-breaking-a-forced-query-store-plan/)

[Deepthi Goguri](https://dbanuggets.com/2021/12/27/query-store-fundamentals-why-my-plan-forcing-has-failed/)

which both suggest that altering of indexes that are used by the plan is the cause of the `NO_PLAN` failure reason.

I set up the extended events session in the second article:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Querystoreforcedplanfailures] ON SERVER 

ADD EVENT qds.query_store_plan_forcing_failed
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\qserror.xel'),
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
WITH (STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO
```

and I can see events for the plan in question, which have the following text:

> Query processor could not produce query plan because USE PLAN hint
> contains plan that could not be verified to be legal for query. Remove
> or replace USE PLAN hint. For best likelihood of successful plan
> forcing, verify that the plan provided in the USE PLAN hint is one
> generated automatically by SQL Server for the same query

The query runs nightly as part of a data warehouse build where DDL commands are common so I decided to set up a Database Audit specification to capture `SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP` action types to see if any indexes were being altered

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT [PlanForceAlters]
TO FILE 
(   FILEPATH = N'P:\Audit\'
    ,MAXSIZE = 0 MB
    ,MAX_ROLLOVER_FILES = 2147483647
    ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
) WITH (QUEUE_DELAY = 1000, ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE, AUDIT_GUID = 'd2b6b090-395f-42f9-a8bb-c0ba742ce30e')
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [PlanForceAlters] WITH (STATE = ON)
GO


USE [MyDatabase]
GO

CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [PlanForceAlters]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [PlanForceAlters]
ADD (SCHEMA_OBJECT_CHANGE_GROUP)
WITH (STATE = ON)
GO
```

When I interrogate the results as follows:

```
SELECT  o.name,
        a.statement
FROM    sys.fn_get_audit_file ('P:\Audit\PlanForce*',default,default) a
        JOIN sys.objects o
            ON o.object_id = a.object_id
WHERE   o.name IN ('MyTableA','MyTable')
```

I can see all the alters for the tables in the IN clause (Which are the tables that are SELECTed from in the query who's plan I am trying to force)

All I can see are foreign key drops and recreates which are fairly normal for our data warehouse. The foreign keys are recreated with the same name they had when they were dropped. The sequence of events is

1. Constraints exist (not trusted)
2. Constraints are dropped
3. Query runs
4. Constraints recreated (same name and NOCHECK)

The plan that has been forced is one that was generated by the query processor at point 3 above so as the sequence of events is the same nightly, I would have thought the change of constraints is irrelevant?

I went further and worked out which columns the foreign keys that were dropped / recreated are on:

```
SELECT  o.name,
        a.statement,
        c.name
FROM    sys.fn_get_audit_file ('P:\Audit\PlanForce*',default,default) a
        JOIN sys.objects o
            ON o.object_id = a.object_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
            ON  statement LIKE '%ADD CONSTRAINT%' + fk.name + '%' OR
                statement LIKE '%DROP CONSTRAINT%' + fk.name + '%' OR
                statement LIKE '%ADD  CONSTRAINT%' + fk.name + '%' OR
                statement LIKE '%DROP  CONSTRAINT%' + fk.name + '%'
        LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
            ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.all_columns c
            ON c.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id AND
                c.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
WHERE   o.name IN ('MyTableA','MyTableB')
```

and none of those are columns in any of the nonclustered indexes used in the query_plan

I have tried to re-create an example on an AdventureWorks2016 database where I force a plan that performs a NCI seek on a column that has a trusted foreign key in place and then observe that the optimizer still uses the plan despite the foreign key being dropped and still uses when it is recreated untrusted:

```
/* create our stored proc */
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE sp_SalesbyProduct
    @ProductID INT
AS
SELECT 
  SalesOrderID, 
  OrderQty,
  UnitPrice
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE ProductID = @ProductID
GO

/* create an index to support the query */
CREATE INDEX IX_SalesOrderDetail_ProductID ON Sales.SalesOrderDetail
(
    ProductId
) 
WITH 
(
    DROP_EXISTING = ON
)

/* add a trusted foreign key on the column IX_SalesOrderDetail_ProductID is on */
ALTER TABLE Sales.SalesOrderDetail ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MyKey FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES Production.Product(ProductId)

/* run the proc and ensure differing plans */
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
EXEC sp_SalesbyProduct @ProductID = 710 /* seek on IX_SalesOrderDetail_ProductID with key lookup */
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
EXEC sp_SalesbyProduct @ProductID = 870 /* CI Scan*/
GO
```

[image]

```
/* force the seek / lookup plan */
EXEC sp_query_store_force_plan 222, 224;

/* verify the plan is forced */
SELECT  *
FROM    sys.query_store_plan
WHERE   is_forced_plan = 1
```

[image]

```
/* run the queries again and ensure both use the seek / lookup plan */

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
EXEC sp_SalesbyProduct @ProductID = 710
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
EXEC sp_SalesbyProduct @ProductID = 870
GO
```

[image]

```
/* drop the constraint on the column in the index */
ALTER TABLE Sales.SalesOrderDetail DROP CONSTRAINT FK_MyKey 

/* is the plan still forced? */

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
EXEC sp_SalesbyProduct @ProductID = 710
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
EXEC sp_SalesbyProduct @ProductID = 870
GO
```

[image]

Yes!

```
/* re-add the FK but make it untrusted */
ALTER TABLE Sales.SalesOrderDetail WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT FK_MyKey FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES Production.Product(ProductId)

/* is the plan still forced? */

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
EXEC sp_SalesbyProduct @ProductID = 710
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
EXEC sp_SalesbyProduct @ProductID = 870
GO
```

[image]

Yes!

What is causing the `NO_PLAN` errors? Is it something to do with the drop / create of foreign key constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropping and recreating *exactly* the same foreign key constraint won't prevent QDS plan forcing.

The word *exactly* there includes the `is_not_trusted` state in `sys.foreign_keys`. The query optimizer doesn't apply simplifications based on a foreign key relationship if the constraint is not trusted.

Trying to force a plan based on a trusted foreign key with a non-trusted foreign key can produce the `NO_PLAN` failure reason.

Equally, trying to a force a plan generated when the foreign key was not trusted may fail when the foreign key is trusted, if simplifications are applied to change the plan shape.

This should be unlikely in your case, since you say you drop and recreate the foreign keys, and `WITH CHECK` is the default for a new constraint. Still, it is something you should verify.

It is also possible you're creating the foreign key with `NOCHECK`, then altering it to `CHECK` status. This does not make the constraint trusted unless you specify `WITH CHECK` as well.

To emphasise the point: This issue arises when a simplification enabled by the trusted foreign key constraint changes the space of plans considered by the optimizer.

An *AdventureWorks* example:

```
-- Force the plan for this query
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) 
FROM Production.Product AS P
JOIN Production.TransactionHistory AS TH
    ON TH.ProductID = P.ProductID;

-- Set the FK to not trusted
ALTER TABLE Production.TransactionHistory
    NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TransactionHistory_Product_ProductID;

-- NO_PLAN
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) 
FROM Production.Product AS P
JOIN Production.TransactionHistory AS TH
    ON TH.ProductID = P.ProductID;

-- Make it trusted again
ALTER TABLE Production.TransactionHistory
    WITH CHECK
        CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_TransactionHistory_Product_ProductID;

-- Plan forced successfully
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*) 
FROM Production.Product AS P
JOIN Production.TransactionHistory AS TH
    ON TH.ProductID = P.ProductID;
```

With a trusted foreign key, the plan is:

[image: Trusted foreign key plan]

When the constraint is not trusted:

[image: Untrusted foreign key plan]

Beyond that, you should start by verifying the plan in QDS can be forced for this query. One test is to use the plan xml in a `USE HINT` manually. This isn't a 100% accurate test since the two mechanisms are quite different, but it may help.

Not all plans stored in QDS are capable of being forced. For complex queries, the optimizer may not be able to find the desired shape, even with the guide. In theory, this should result in a `TIME_OUT` forcing failure reason, but it doesn't always. You should verify that the plan is ever successfully forced before looking further for reasons it failed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out not to be anything to do with constraints but is something to do with the query itself.

A cut down, anonymized version of the query is below:

```
SELECT  1
        -- some text so I can pick it out of query_store_sql_text more easily
        FROM    Object1 WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN Object2 Object2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON ? = Object2.Column1
            AND ? = Object2.Column2
            AND Object1.Column3 = Object2.Column4
        INNER JOIN Object3 Object3 WITH (NOLOCK) ON Object1.Column5 = Object3.Column5
            AND Object1.Column6 >= Object3.Column7
            AND Object3.Column8 IS NULL
        INNER JOIN Object4 Object5 WITH (NOLOCK) ON ? = Object5.Column9
        LEFT JOIN Object4 WITH (NOLOCK) ON Object4.Column9 = ?
        LEFT JOIN Object6 ON Object6.Column10 = CAST(Object5.Column4 + ? AS VARCHAR(255))
            AND Object6.Column11 = Object1.Column12
            AND Object6.Column13 = Object3.Column13
            AND Object6.Column5 = Object3.Column5
            AND Object6.Column14 = ?
WHERE   (Object4.Column4 = ? OR Object4.Column4 IS NULL)
```

the plan is [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkA9H-9bj)

I

- Run the query
- get the query_id and plan_id from the query store dmvs
- force the query to the plan
- run the query again
- the plan shows as `NO_PLAN` in `sys.query_store_plan.last_force_failure_reason_desc`

I have managed to track this down to the WHERE clause (the where clause is much larger on the real query but commenting bits out one by lead to this predicate being the problem)

I still can't explain why but I now have a reproducable example in my environment. I just need to see if I can replicate this in AdventureWorks.

I am marking Paul Whites answer as the accepted answer as in terms of the original theory of constraints being at fault, it is correct